# pass form name to a user control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a User control with a textbox. I want to pass the text from textbox on the User control back to the parent form, when the text changes.

I found the following code in my user control which work well for doing this. This includes a TextChanged event.

```
    public string pub_callsign
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var textBoxContent = this.textBox1.Text;
        var parent = this.Parent as form1;
        parent.pub_callsign = pub_callsign;
    }
```

In my parent form I have

```
    public string pub_callsign
    {
        set { txtbx_callsign.Text = value; }
    }
```

However I would like to use this User Control on more than 3 form,

So how do I get the form name from the form to the user control. Thereby  what is shown below as form1 or form2 to be a variable containing the formname ??

```
var parent = this.Parent as form1;

var parent = this.Parent as form2;

var parent = this.Parent as formname_value;
```

hope this makes sense.

Dave

Comment: Don't do that. Don't asume anything about the form that'll use the control. Instead, create a public property which simply gets/sets the textbox. Any form using it can call the property and use it in any way it sees fit.

Comment: And also a public event.

Comment: I get the feeling my question is being misunderstood.

I have and event in my user control that when the text in the textbox changes it need to send the text back to the main form.

This event works, but is dependent on having the form name as per the code above.

Comment: @DaveBishop - No, it's not. You just need to expose a public event and public property and any form can access the field.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a property in the user control that gives you access to the text box contents.

   ```
   public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
   {
       public UserControl1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public string Contents { get => textBox1.Text; set => textBox1.Text = value; }
   }
   ```
2. In the form use the property to read the contents of the text box

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public void ReadContents()
       {
           var contents = userControl11.Contents;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You would typically also add an event to the user control so that the form can detect change without having to know the details of the user control.

Comment: I thought that was what I have done. but can you give me a code example

Comment: @DaveBishop - You've done the opposite. You've enabled the child form to update the parent. You need the parent to be able to access the child.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to have the user control tell the parent - no matter if the parent is a form or other user control - that the value of the text box has changed.

I created a user control called `MyUserControl` with a single text box called `textBox1`.

I added a `TextBoxTextChanged` event to `MyUserControl` and ended up with the following code:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> TextBoxTextChanged;

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TextBoxTextChanged?.Invoke(this, textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Now, on `Form1`, I added the an instance of `MyUserControl` called `myUserControl1` and added the handler for `TextBoxTextChanged`. I ended up with this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void myUserControl1_TextBoxTextChanged(object sender, string e)
    {
        this.label1.Text = e;
    }
}
```

When I run that the text in the user control is automatically updated in the label as I type.

[image: Form1]

Answer (score -3):

Where do you want to put the text box text? If it's in the title bar, do this:

`formName.Text = yourTextBox.Text;`

If it's in a label or another text box, do the same thing but use the control with its text property, and set it to the text box's text property.